# Should I always deep clone React's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a Tic Tac Toe game with React.

The click handler for the game cells look like this:

```
function onClick(row, cell) {
    if (!state.game[row][cell]) {
        state.game[row][cell] = state.player === 1 ? 1 : 2;
        state.player = state.player === 1 ? 2 : 1;
        setState({ ...state });
    }
}
```

I am basically mutating the old state and reusing it as a new state by copying its properties in a new object (in order to create a new reference).

Despite this, the references to the `state.game` arrays remain the same, so I'm wondering if it's fine to do this or if it's bug prone and if a state in React should always be deep cloned.

Comment: It's not a deep clone. And it should not work as you expect: `state.game[row][cell]` this is nested too deep, so `...state` does not really clone it, if you remove `state.player = state.player === 1 ? 2 : 1;` mutation you would be able to see that.

Comment: I know that it's not a deep clone but my question is, do I need a deep clone or does React handle shallow clones correctly? So far my app works fine but is it always the case?

Comment: "React handle shallow clones correctly" --- react does not care: it compares values. "So far my app works fine" --- it's an accident, remove `player` mutation and see it would break, because `state.game[row][cell] = ...` does not really change the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can cause bugs. It may be that this top level component doesn't show a bug, because the only thing that it cares about has a new reference. But if you pass sections of the state to other components as props, they may get thrown off by the mutation.

So you should create a copy at each level that you are changing. For example:

```
function onClick(row, cell) {
  if(!state.game[row][cell]) {
    const newRow = [...state.game[row]];
    newRow[cell] = state.player === 1 ? 1 : 2;

    const newGame = [...state.game];
    newGame[row] = newRow;

    setState({
      ...state,
      player: state.player === 1 ? 2 : 1,
      game: newGame,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that a sub-component could not update because it receives the same reference of a prop? I could not figure it out myself.

Comment: Correct. For example, a sub-component might receive a row as a prop, and it checks that prop to see if the reference changed. Since you mutated, the reference did not change, and the subcomponent incorrectly thinks it doesn't have to render.

Answer (score 1):

Mutating state may cause issue that React will not see changes and will not re-render your components.

If your state is complex it is easier to use [`lodash.cloneDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to make a copy and then mutate the copy but keep previous state intact.

```
import _cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';
...
function onClick(row, cell) {
    if (!state.game[row][cell]) {
        const newState = _cloneDeep(state);
        newState.game[row][cell] = state.player === 1 ? 1 : 2;
        newState.player = state.player === 1 ? 2 : 1;
        setState(newState);
    }
}
```